# VIm omni complete doesn't work for python variable?

Tags: python, vim, editor, omnicomplete

I would like to use omnicomplete instead of writing every variable myself. Soon, I have to work on a chaotic project so I need some help for finding variable... I tried to use omnicomplete but it doesn't work:

You will find below some softwares informations:

VIM : 7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
exuberant-ctag : 5.9

My .vimrc:

```
set background=dark
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set ai

au BufWinEnter * let w:m1=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
highlight Space ctermbg=darkblue guibg=darkblue
highlight Tab ctermbg=darkgray guibg=darkgray
au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('Tab', '\t', -1)
au BufWinEnter * let w:m3=matchadd('Space', '\s\+$\| \+\ze\t', -1)

map <F4> :TlistToggle<cr>
filetype plugin on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

When i open a file i enter this:

:set tags=/mypath/myfile

But when I want an automatic completion it doesn't work:

self.

It shows only function name and no variable?
When i use TagLisst, I see only functions too. If I read my tags file, I can find my variables..

So what I have to do if I want to use omnicomplete for completing variable in python script?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `omnifunc` line should be enough. It explicitely replaces the default python omnifunc (which does what you want) with a less capable one.

Comment: ello, it doesn't work. I still don't have access to self.my_variable. I removed : set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete Same VIM behavior. Do I declare well my variable? I do it directly under : class xxxx: my_var1 my_var2 ? Anyway, I don't have variable in my constructor too...

Comment: Since `filetype plugin on` is in the vimrc file, the python ftplugin will set `'omnifunc'`, so it does not matter how that option is set in the vimrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think I have a deeper issue with Vi and exuberant-ctags.

You will find below my new vimrc:

```
set background=dark
set ai


let Tlist_WinWidth = 50
highlight Space ctermbg=darkblue guibg=darkblue
highlight Tab ctermbg=darkgray guibg=darkgray
au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('Tab', '\t', -1)
au BufWinEnter * let w:m3=matchadd('Space', '\s\+$\| \+\ze\t', -1)

map <F4> :TlistToggle<cr>
map! <F3> <C-V><Tab>

filetype plugin indent on


set completeopt=longest,menuone
```

When I do that:

```
:set tags=/mypath/myfile
```

Then if I try to enter:

```
:ts
```

I get :

E73 : tag stack empty

or :TlistShowTag => nothing happens

I don't understand where is the mistake? Vim configuration? TagList? Exuberant-tags? :/

Why I have variable namy in my tags file but not in tag list? :(

Comment: I can only access to my variable when I instance an object.. Else when I'm writing in my object, unable to access to variable :(